# How can I modify this class to use the singleton pattern, like activemodel?

Tags: ruby, singleton, httparty

I have a httparty "model" which I use like so

```
myRest = RestModel.new
myRest.someGetResquest()
myRest.somePostRequest()
```

How would I go about changing it to work similarly to an activemodel, like so?

```
RestModel.someGetRequest()
RestModel.somePostRequest()
```

this [blog post](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again) shows how to include the singleton module but its still accesses the instance like this: `RestModel.instance.someGetRequest()`

here is my code:

```
class Managementdb
    include HTTParty

    base_uri "http://localhost:7001/management/"

    def initialise(authToken)
        self.authToken = authToken
    end

    def login()
        response = self.class.get("/testLogin")
        if response.success?
          self.authToken = response["authToken"]
        else
          # this just raises the net/http response that was raised
          raise response.response    
        end
    end

    attr_accessor :authToken

    ...
end
```

Please tell me that I am doing it all wrong (show me the light)

Comment: Using the singleton pattern will always access it using `RestModel.instance.method()`, the get accessor for instance checks if one has been created and returns that instance or creates one if it has not been used previously.  Using it with `RestModel.method()` would be the way a static class would operate, not a singleton

Comment: ok, do you mind if I change the title.

Comment: @jzworkman That's not true in Ruby. "Class" or "static" methods and properties in Ruby exist on the class's singleton object. Ruby isn't Java.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall True, I posted an answer below, forgot about the self tag for a second.

Comment: @jzworkman `self` isn't a tag, it's an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `extend` rather than `include`, which will add the methods onto the class singleton, rather than making them available on instances.

```
class Managementdb
  extend HTTParty
end
```

a longer example illustrating this:

```
module Bar
  def hello
    "Bar!"
  end
end
module Baz
  def hello
    "Baz!"
  end
end
class Foo
  include Bar
  extend Baz
end

Foo.hello     # => "Baz!"
Foo.new.hello # => "Bar!"
```

Comment: can I still use a method in `Baz` from `Foo`?

Comment: @JosephLeBrech I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly, can you clarify?

Comment: If `Baz` has another method how do I call it from a method in `Foo`?

Comment: @JosephLeBrech Same way you would anywhere else: `Foo.hello`.